# Connecting VB.net program to Dropbox

Tags: vb.net, dropbox, owncloud

I'm writing a VB.net program but I would like it to be linked to Dropbox. I have Application Forms and Quotes etc that are accessed on a daily basis from Dropbox, I want to change it so that the employees access it through a windows application but also, globally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to link to Dropbox "the right way", look into [SharpBox](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/).

A simpler but cruder solution is to require users to install Dropbox on any PC they wish to run your application on.

```
Imports System.IO
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim filePath As String = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\dropbox\"
    If Directory.Exists(filePath) Then
        'Program may proceed
    Else
        MsgBox("You must install Dropbox on this computer in order for this application to function properly.")
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that you should test for a specific file or folder within Dropbox if there is a possibility that someone will use your program on a machine that has dropbox installed but under a different username than your program accesses.